# R: Webscraping data not contained in HTML

Tags: r, xml, web-scraping, rvest

I'm trying to webscrape in R from webpages such as [these](https://www.caschooldashboard.org/reports/01611766000590/2020). But the html is only 50 lines so I'm assuming the numbers are hidden in a javascript file or on their server. I'm not sure how to find the numbers I want (e.g., the enrollment number under student population).

When I try to use rvest, as in

```
num <- school_webpage %>%
  html_elements(".number no-mrg-btm") %>% 
  html_text()
```

I get an error that says "could not find function "html_elements"" even though I've installed and loaded rvest.

What's my best strategy for getting those various numbers and why am I getting that error message? Thnx.

Answer (score 0):

That data is coming from an API request you can find in the browser network tab. It returns json. Make a request direct to that page (as you don't have a browser to do this based off landing page):

```
library(jsonlite)

data <- jsonlite::read_json('https://api.caschooldashboard.org/LEAs/01611766000590/6/true')
print(data$enrollment)
```